# Storing object in session - struts2

Tags: session, struts2

Hi I have something like this in struts.xml

```
   <action name="LoginAction" class="controller.LoginAction">
                <result name="error">/Error.jsp</result>
                <result name="success">/Wizard.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Edited:

Upon successful execution of `execute` in the action the next page has data which it accesses using the request scope. How can i store the same data in session scope instead?

I read that `HttpServletRequest` object is passed as a parameter to the `execute()` method in a Struts action, and I can always retrieve the `HttpSession` object by using the `request.getSession()` and attaching data to it.

So if I am using something like this in `controller.LoginAction`

```
public String execute(HttpServletRequest req) {
    ...
}
```

Do I have to change `struts.xml`? `execute` does not get called when `HttpServletRequest` is added as a parameter.

```
   <action name="LoginAction" class="controller.LoginAction">
                <result name="error">/Error.jsp</result>
                <result name="success">/Wizard.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Also is using session this way the best method ? I am trying to familiarize my self with the struts method.

Comment: other way to persist data than session or other way to store data in session. This is the perfect way to store data into session.

Comment: Just edited my original post with another question

Comment: You read incorrectly or what you read was wrong; S2 action methods don't take any parameters.

Comment: That explains why the execute method wont be called with parameters. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: If I remember correctly, struts1 action methods took such parameters. I guess you got confused because of that

Comment: Exactly I thought that struts2 also has that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement [SessionAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html) interface:

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    private Map session;

    public String execute() {
        session.put("key", "value");
        // Plus any additional action code
    }

    // Plus setter (and optionally getter) for session map.
}
```

Alternate way using `ActionContext` is explained [here](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2-login.shtml).

`SessionAware` is preferred over `ActionContext`. Here are some discussions on that:

- [Should I get the session through SessionAware or ActionContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401576/struts2-obtaining-session-through-sessionaware-or-actioncontext)
- [SessionAware vs ActionContext access to session - confused](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/SessionAware-vs-ActionContext-access-to-session-confused-td3469328.html)